# Why does the ii-V-i-IV progression in this video have chords from a different key?

Tags: theory, piano, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I've been learning about chord progressions and found myself with the one shown in the video embedded at the end of this post.

At 2:25, the narrator selects a software-built-in chord progression: ii-V-i-IV in C# minor.

[image: Chord selection at 2:25 of YouTube video "The Truth about the Unison MIDI Chord Pack..."]

But when the chords are displayed at 2:26, ...

[image: Chords shown at 2:26 of YouTube video "The Truth about the Unison MIDI Chord Pack..."]

... I don't understand why the bass note is only used as a bass note for another chord (e.g., Amaj13 / D#). **What theory describes this?**

Further, when I reverse-search the chords used in the progression (e.g., Amaj13, Cmaj7b5, B6/11), they don't fit within the key of C# minor. **Where do these chords come from?**

---

Comment: Could you write the chords as text in the question, please? :)

Comment: As Aaron stated, it would be D#-7b5 - G#7#5#9 - C#9 - F#9add13, but there is a note missing from each chord based on what the sample plays out. For example, in C#9 chord, the sample plays the note C# B D# E G#; meanwhile C#9 chord only has the following notes: C# F G# B D#, which doesn't have E note.

Comment: I get tired of _videos_ posted as questions, it's just a transcription request in disguise, because you need to transcribe to know that any of the symbols are right to begin with

Comment: @MichaelCurtis FYI: I've updated to clarify that the question doesn't involve transcription.

Comment: @Aaron, now I'm transcribing a piano scroll. The OP should write out the chords in a _readable_ way: RNA, jazz symbols, or god forbid staff notation!

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Readable is relative. Any guitar tab question requires me to "transcribe" in the same sense you're using here. And I don't think we want to close every notation question involving a DAW using this type of display. OP did include chord symbols, BTW.

Comment: It would depend on the tab question. If it's about performance execution, probably OK. If it's some harmony/analysis question, the OP ought to do something spare everyone the transcribing. I don't mind down voting/closing DAW or Synthesia videos when the question is about RNA and traditional analysis.

Answer (score 1):

When examining chords, all of the notes must be considered, not just one hand. Also, a chord keeps its identity regardless the order in which the notes appear.

The chords are:

| Chord symbol | video voicing | root position | Roman numeral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D#m7b5#11 | D# A C# F# G# | D# F# A C# G# | iim7b5#11 |
| G#7#5#9 | G# C E F# B | G# B# Dx F# Ax | V7#5#7 |
| C#m9 | C# B D# E G# | C# E G# B D# | i9 |
| F#9add13 | F# A# D# E G# | F# A# E G# D# | IV9add13 |

Comment: I found a note missing from each chord: no G# note in D#-7b5; no C note in G#7#5#9; no E note in C#9; and no E note in F#9add13. Why do the chords have these notes? The notes don't compose the chord.

Comment: @dave.s I missed the G# in the first chord; the answer is updated now. I don't understand the problems with the other three; please clarify.

Comment: @dave.s I fixed the C#9 problem. It should have been C#m9, which does contain E rather than E# (=F).

Comment: I got wrong there. The answer is clear now.

Comment: @dave.s Just checking in to see if there's anything more that you need from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basic transcription and analysis questions are supposed to be off topic.

But, part of the confusion is the software. The chords are not simply `C#m ii V i IV`

I'm not going to transcribe and analyze the whole thing, the problems can be understood by the first chord alone.

First, it is not `C#m: ii`. If we keep it to just a simple seventh chord label, without putting in non-chord tone stuff, it's a *half diminished seventh chord* which is `C#m: iiø7` or in jazz symbols `D#m7♭5`. If you try using the software progression label, it's confusing, because the actual part isn't simple triads. The `V` also looks like it should be an altered chord, some kind of `Valt7`.

Next, the full tones of the chord ascending are `D# A C# F# G#`, reorder that as a tertian stack to get `D# F# A C# G#`. That's a `D#` half diminished with the `G#` as an eleventh, extended harmony or `sus/add` doesn't really matter at this point. The important thing is we have a clear root position half diminished chord.

You could reorder the tertian stack using a different supposed root: `A C# G# D# F#` and call it an `Amaj13` with the `D#` a `sus#4`.

> ...I don't understand why the bass note is only used as a bass note for another chord (e.g., Amaj13 / D#). What theory describes this?

*Analysis* is what describes it. A proper analysis would first determine what the tonic is, but we can just stick with the assumption `C#` is the tonic and the mode is minor. A bass movement of `D# G# C#...` - descending perfect fifths - certainly reinforces `C#` minor.

The question then is why `D#m7♭5` is not simply interchangeable with `Amaj13(sus#4)/D#`.

The answer won't come from just looking up a list of tones in an online tool. You need to understand principles of chord voicing, especially how inversions and the bass work.

For basic, practical harmony, you normally have the chord root in the bass with movement by fifths/fourths. When the chord is inverted other chord tones like the third, fifth, seventh are in the bass, and the bass will move step-wise. Additionally, with extended chords the extensions ninth, eleventh, thirteenth are *not* normally in the bass.

So, we have the choices of:

- a `D#` bass for a root position chord, moving by descending fifth to `G#`
- a `D#` bass for an inverted, extended chord, with a sharp eleventh in the bass, moving not by step, but by *leap* to `G#`

Basic voicing and voice leading principles say the first options is typical.

It's much more straight forward to say the `D#` bass is a root to a root position chord than the eleventh of odd inversion of an extended chord.

Follow that principle for the other chord, which are in root position, and then go back and fix the Roman numeral analysis errors of the software label for the progression, and things will make more sense.